# Subversion problem, repo has moved

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I've set up subversion on a CentOS fresh install. Web view works fine and gives no errors and requests password but when I try and access it through svn client (xcode) it gives the error 175011 (Repository has been moved).

I've tried some of the solutions out there but no success. My subversion.conf:

```
<Location /repos>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/html/repos

# Limit write permission to list of valid users.
  # Require SSL connection for password protection.
  SSLRequireSSL

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authorization Realm"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

My Apache DocumentRoot: /var/www/html

I've only set up one svn repository so far so there shouldn't be any conflicts there. If you need any more info let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing <Location /repos> to <Location /repos/>. Also do the error occur on checkout or in an update ? (if its the later then perhaps you need to do a svn switch).

Comment: Tried adding / to the location with no success, from memory it actually kills the webview. The error occurs when I try to connect to the repo from Xcode so presumably I won't be able to do either to it as the setup of the repo fails. I am using xcode to connect to another subversion and that works fine so its not xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this was a conflict with apache / subversion or some kind of bug but after placing the repo somewhere other than in /var/www/html/repos it works. I placed mine in /var/www/repos and used exactly the same config and it worked.